# Utilizing Mission Control

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

recently I've gotten into trying to utilize the DJI Mobile SDK as a little side project of mine. I've been working in Swift utilizing the samples provided by DJI on their Github but I've been having an issue utilizing the missionControl and honestly I'm not even sure if missionControl is the best way to go about doing it.

Goal: Simply what I'm trying to achieve is that I just want the drone to fly up to a specified height and take video footage of what is below it. I'm not even concerned with horizontal motion right now, just vertical motion.

What I've Done: Utilizing their sample, I've gotten the drone to record video footage, but I am unable to get it to truly fly. My first approach was to use flightController and I've succeeded in getting it to take off and land, but I do not believe their is a method such as goToLocation() or something of the sort. This is the functioning methods that do take off and landing.

```
@IBAction func takeOffPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let aircraft = DJISDKManager.product() as? DJIAircraft {
        aircraft.flightController?.startTakeoff(completion: nil)
    }else{
        self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title:"Action", withMessage: "Product Connection Not Found")
    }
}

@IBAction func landPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let aircraft = DJISDKManager.product() as? DJIAircraft {
        aircraft.flightController?.startLanding(completion: nil)
    }else{
        self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title:"Action", withMessage: "Product Connection Not Found")
    }
}
```

Although I got the drone to takeOff, that is not truly flight so instead I started looking into the missionControl class where there seems to be missions to achieve the functionality that I want, however my code seems to not be correct because it does not cause the drone to perform any action. If there is someone here more experienced with the DJI SDK, I would appreciate any help that you may be able to give. My non functioning code is below.

```
@IBAction func doMission(_ sender: Any) {
    var elements = [DJIMissionControlTimelineElement]()
    elements.append(DJITakeOffAction())
    elements.append(DJIGoToAction(altitude: 1)!)
    elements.append(DJIGoHomeAction())
    DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.scheduleElements(elements)
    DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.startTimeline()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeline mission needs a few adjustments, including the altitude of the go to action and the addition of a DJIRecordVideoAction to record video for your desired duration. Try the modified code below:

```
@IBAction func doMission(_ sender: Any) {
    var elements = [DJIMissionControlTimelineElement]()
    elements.append(DJITakeOffAction())
    elements.append(DJIGoToAction(altitude: 5)!)
    elements.append(DJIRecordVideoAction(duration: 10)!) // this assumes a desired duration of 10 seconds
    elements.append(DJIGoHomeAction())
    DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.scheduleElements(elements)
    DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.startTimeline()
}
```

You can also make use of `DJIMissionControl` `addListener:toTimelineProgressWithBlock:` method to add additional diagnostics to your code as it will be called for each timeline event including start and finish of all elements.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I don't have continual access to the drone, but I finally got to test today. Not sure why but I seem to be having issues. I tried utilizing the code you provided, and the drone doesn't seem to be registering the actions. It performs the TakeOffAction() and DJIGoHomeAction() but it doesn't perform the DJIRecordVideoAction() or the DJIGoHomeAction(). Would having live video feed coming in from the drone conflict with these mission actions?

Comment: When you call DJISDKManager.missionControl()?.scheduleElements(elements), do you see it return an error?

Comment: No, it does not return any error. It does not make sense to me why it performs the TakeOff and GoHome but seems to ignore any actions I wish to perform in between.

Comment: Add a listener block to mission control via `DJIMissionControl addListener:toTimelineProgressWithBlock:` and log the `event`, `element`, and `error` parameters that will be supplied as the timeline runs. See if the elements you expect are returned and and also if there's any errors.

Comment: Its returning the correct elements, but it is giving an error in the action listener. Optional(<DJIGoToAction: 0x141b4b950>)
 
Optional(Error Domain=DJISDKMissionErrorDomain Code=-5024 "Command cannot be executed.(code:-5024)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Command cannot be executed.(code:-5024)})

Comment: Wow okay, apparently the code I had from the beginning was working the entire time. On the Mavic pro, goToActions are disabled in WIFI mode. Went to RC mode and everything works fine.